# Unable to create a new list in sharepoint online using graph sdk

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have backed up the list from my site and deleted some list from it.
Now I wanted to restore a List inside Site.

To restore list I used create List graph call(since the list was deleted) and passed all the data from the list that I backed up(excluding Name attribute).

The List that I passed as an argument is:

```
displayName : "qwerty"
list
columns
contentTypes
createdBy
createdDateTime : "2019-08-07T15:26:45+05:30"
description : ""
eTag : ""4aa6af8e-32d6-4ca9-ac0a-02c8e110f65d,6""
lastModifiedDateTime : "2019-08-07T15:26:45+05:30"
name : null
parentReference
webUrl : "https://dextorlab.sharepoint.com/sites/HelloWorld/Lists/qwerty"
id : "4aa6af8e-32d6-4ca9-ac0a-02c8e110f65d"
@odata.etag : ""4aa6af8e-32d6-4ca9-ac0a-02c8e110f65d,6
```

The Graph Call that is made is:

```
var ListResult = _SharepointOperations._GraphCLient.Sites[_SiteId].Lists.Request().AddAsync(siteList).Result;
```

I expect the output as successful, but graph return "one or more errors occurred" with inner error as "Unable to determine type of provided column definition"

Comment: The column definition is likely in the variable "columns" - perhaps you could post the value of that variable?

Comment: As Paul mentioned, without clarity on what that columns property contains, it is difficult to answer this question.

Comment: Please refer this for column definition https://dextorlab-my.sharepoint.com/:t:/g/personal/subhanu_dextorlab_onmicrosoft_com/EfJ9dq8olnBErZE989rNF5EBPlKM0CjSJ8efT3zO5K_Bfw?e=BdejdT

Answer (score 1):

You need format the siteList like below.

```
var siteList = new List
{
    DisplayName = "Books",
    Columns = new List<ColumnDefinition>()
    {
        new ColumnDefinition
        {
            Name = "Author",
            Text = new TextColumn
            {
            }
        },
        new ColumnDefinition
        {
            Name = "PageCount",
            Number = new NumberColumn
            {
            }
        }
    },
    List = new ListInfo
    {
        Template = "genericList"
    }
};
```

Article: [Create a new list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/list-create?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp)

To add items to the list using this.

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var listItem = new ListItem
{
    Fields = new FieldValueSet
    {
        Title = "Widget",
        Color = "Purple",
        Weight = 32
    }
};

await graphClient.Sites["{site-id}"].Lists["{list-id}"].Items
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(listItem);
```

Comment: This would be used if I want to create a new list with all my column. But I want to create list from the data which I backed up earlier.

Comment: You can't just use the data you pulled. That data will have a slew of read-only properties (`id`, `etag`, etc.). You need to reach the data, populate a new `List` object, and pass _that_ to Graph.

Comment: Agree with the Marc's reply, you need get the data from your backup data first, then pass data to a new List Object in Graph.